# Slim lang inline lists not working

Tags: slim-lang

I'm converting some existing HTML files to Slim (https://github.com/stonean/slim) and using it for the first time but I'm having problems getting lists to work in compact form (meaning all on one line rather than indented below). The docs say:

> Inline tags
>
> Sometimes you may want to be a little more compact and inline the
>   tags.

```
ul
  li.first: a href="/a" A link
  li: a href="/b" B link
```

But when I try that I get this output in the browser:

a href="/b" B

With the rendered HTML looking like this in the source:

```
<li:>a href="/b" B link</li:>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working and how to fix it?

Comment: Pasting `ul
  li.first: a href="/a" A link
  li: a href="/b" B link` works perfectly fine for me. I get `A link` and 
`B link` in the browser. The HTML source says `<ul><li class="first"><a href="/a">A link</a></li><li><a href="/b">B link</a></li></ul>`
. Do try it one more time.

Comment: It's definitely not working for me. Here's a screenshot showing my code editor contents, how it displays in the browser and then what's generated in the source code: http://cl.ly/ErN0

Comment: Update your slim version... also, to convert files you can use https://github.com/slim-template/html2slim

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct and the output for me (slim 1.3.0) is, as expected:

```
<ul><li class="first"><a href="/a">A link</a></li><li><a href="/b">B link</a></li></ul>
```

You should check your slim version and update appropriately.